# how to disable accesskey in WPF menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

WPF removes the underscore that i'm writing in menuitem tag, how can disable the access key option in menuitem so I can see the underscore in my UI,
here is my menuitem code:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding UserName}"
                          HeaderStringFormat="{WPFCommon:LocalizeExtension Key=Hello, Type='PortalHeader.Views.AppHeader, PortalHeader.Views'}"

                          Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static philipsStyles:StyleResourceKeys.MenuItemSingleDropdownResourceKey}}" >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two consecutive underscores would show as a single underscore (and won't be used for access key purposes).

For example:

```
<MenuItem Header="__Hello_World" />
```

Would render as:

```
_HelloWorld
```

With the letter "W" as the access key.

Another option is to use a `HeaderTemplate` that would force WPF to ignore all access keys.

Put this template in a resource dictionary:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringOnlyTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And use it:

```
<MenuItem HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource StringOnlyTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the fast response, but I don't want this workaround, it breaks the automation, I can't insert two consecutive underscores,
I just want to disable the access key.